# Fast find in list of lists

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Consider the following function:

```
import Data.List (find)     
findInLists items = map $ find (`elem` items)
```

Which can be called like so with the following result:

```
findInLists [2,3] [[1,2], [1,3,2], [4, -2, 8]] -> [Just 2, Just 3, Nothing]
```

The first argument can be assumed to be sorted, but the second argument will not be sorted.

If `n` is the total number of items in all lists to be searched (in this particular case, 7, as the search stops once an item is found) and `k` is the number of items to search for, I believe the runtime of this function will be `O(n * k)`. However, this is bad for large `k` when `n` is also large.

I would like the runtime to be more like `O(n * log k) + O(k * log k)` or better if possible. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify:  If there are two matches, such as in `findInLists [2,3] [[1,3,2]]`, it is OK to return `[Just 2]`, or must it be `[Just 3]`?  In other words, do you require the first match, or just to find any match in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stick the `items` in a `Set` and use [`member`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Set.html#v:member).

Answer (score 6):

```
import Data.Set (fromList,member)
import Data.List
findInLists :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [Maybe a]
findInLists xs = map $ find $ flip member $ fromList xs
```

`fromList xs` will take `O(k log k)` one time and each `find` will take `O(log k)` in worst case. So total time for n elements = `O(n log k) + O(k log k)` worst case.